# JDBC and SQLException

Tags: java, jdbc, exception

I am having a Java class with several methods like this

```
public void someMethod (Collection<object> objects) throws Exception
```

This program sometimes throws java.sql.SQLException like a Oracle deadlock but on the serverside i dont see a tracefile.

Is it advisiable to modify the method signatures to something more specific like

```
public void someMethod (Collection<object> objects) throws SQLException
```

and then in the method try the prepared statements in **try catch block** would it help to catch the actual exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a method as `throws Exception` isn't good practice. You should be specific about what exceptions your method throws, so `throws SQLException` is better and more descriptive.

Your try/catch block around that method call will work regardless of whether you use `throws Exception` or `throws SQLException`. If you need to trap the deadlock, then catch the `SQLException` and handle it there.

If you don't handle it there, then the exception will bubble up the stack until it is either caught somewhere, or the program (or thread) exits.

Comment: whats the best practices allow the exception to bubble up or have it handled in the method that is throwing the exception